# SharePoint Online get site/drive permissions REST API

Tags: rest, sharepoint

From onedrive REST API doc https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/onedrive/developer/rest-api/, I cannot find API to get permissions of sites/drives. 
  Now I need to get one site/drive permission, I can get drive info only. In drive information, there are "CreateBy" and "Ower group" info only. But I need site/drive permission details. Is there such REST API?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you need application permission.

You can try `Sites.Manage.All` to manage delegated and application permission.

In application permission. `Sites.Manage.All` can give you full control of all site collections

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I have added application permission. But I don't know what's the Microsoft Graph REST API to get site/drive permission setting.

Comment: Here are two MS docs may help ya to understand how to get permission from MS Graph https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/permissions_reference#sites-permissions.   ******** https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference

Comment: Hi, I think you don't get my point. I know how to set permission for my azuer ad APP. Now I want to get the permission setting of one site/drive with REST API.  Now I want to sync file from SharePoint with my PC. I should get the permission setting first. But I have check all docs, it looks like that there is no REST API to get permission setting of site/drive.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have api to get the permission of the sites/drives(root drive) now.

You can try the following API to get the permission of items/item if you need:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_list_permissions

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/permission_get

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following link:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a18c8154-29bb-4197-bda4-462e3d07a485/need-rest-api-for-fetching-permissions-of-site-collections-and-document-libraries-in-sharepoint?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

You find the REST APIs and usage details.